# Angularjs and Web Services

Tags: json, angularjs, web-services

I make a web services which returns me a JSON formatted data when I use this url(http://localhost:8080/jerseyweb/crunchify/ftocservice). Now I want to get those data through `Angular js` but I can not get it. The code with which I try that is as follow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

 <ul>
 <li ng-repeat="x in names">
{{ x.id + ', ' + x.name }}
</li>
 </ul>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
     alert("hi");
    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/jerseyweb/crunchify/ftocservice")
     .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
alert("hiee"); // i can not reach at this alert
  $scope.names = data;


});
});
</script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

The JSON data in http://localhost:8080/jerseyweb/crunchify/ftocservice is as following

```
[{"id":98.24,"name":36.8}]
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console?? In addition i think that success function get only one parameter (data). Try to remove all the others parameters

Comment: I try that but i can not get any thing in out put........

Comment: Not also get any error but i try debug and found that debug call not able to get into this:$http.get("http://localhost:8080/jerseyweb/crunchify/ftocservice")
     .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
alert("hiee"); // i can not reach at this alert
  $scope.names = data;


});

Comment: try adding a .error(function(data){...}) to see if it goes in.

Comment: yes i just try that and it goes in ..........

Comment: does that url show valid json when opened in browser? Is web service on different port than page you call it from? Inspect the actual request in browser dev tool network for more clues

Comment: I also check that one and both url and json data are valid....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in Web Services Response.....

```
@OPTIONS
@Path("/getsample")
public Response getOptions() {
return Response.ok()
  .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
  .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, UPDATE, OPTIONS")
  .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With")
.build();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code might be it's use full :

```
var response = $http({
                method: "GET",
                url: "http://localhost:8080/jerseyweb/crunchify/ftocservice",
                dataType: "json"
            });



response.then(function (obj) {
            $scope.names = obj.data.name;
        }, function () {
            alert('Error.');
        });
```

If data comes from the API in string format then use

```
var objdata = JSON.parse(obj.data);
$scope.names = objdata.name;
```

Comment: If API also same location then use 

url: "/jerseyweb/crunchify/ftocservice",

Comment: Ok....I have a web services which one return me a JSON format data as a stated above.....Now i want to get that data using angular js .But i can not fetch that data using URL(which i mention). And the call goes to error part rather than in a response part. And get error which i wright in alert.